# Playstore display wrong update for the android app

Tags: android, version

We have recently update the app before approx 6 hours ago and when I come back to computer and check that app is updated or not, playstore updated wrong version app instead what I updated at 6 hours ago. Playstored updated my internal testing app version instead.

What should we do now?

Both internal testing app version code / code name and todays updated version code / name are different.

Playstore description is old instead new which is i updated today and also playstore display,

Updated on
Aug 31, 2023

which is also wrong, it is date of my internal testing app version not todays uploaded app.

I uploaded the app for internal testing approx 20 days ago but today I finally release the new version.